# Entity Framework required:optional 1 to 1 relationship with two navigation properties

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am trying to establish a required:optional 1 to 1 relationship between two entities, where both entities have navigation properties referencing each other. I only want a single foreign key on the `Location` object. A `Photo` must have a `Location`, but a `Location` doesn't need to have a `Photo`

Here are both models, I have no additional Fluent code describing the relationship.

```
public class Photo
{
    [Column("PhotoID")]
    public long ID { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Photo")]
    [Required]
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
}


public class Location
{
    [Column("LocationID")]
    public long LocationID { get; set; }

    public long? PhotoID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ID")]
    public virtual Photo Photo{ get; set; }
}
```

The sql it generates creates a constraint that points to the wrong foreign key on the Photo object.

```
FOREIGN KEY FK_dbo.Photo_dbo.Location_PhotoID   No Action   No Action   Enabled Is_For_Replication  PhotoID
                        REFERENCES Relationships.dbo.Location (LocationID)
```

Comment: Your [ForeignKey("ID")] is in the wrong place, it needs to decorate public long? PhotoID { get; set; }

Comment: I'm not a fan of "implicit" relationships.  Better to add LocationID to Photo as a nullable long and add the modelBuilder.Entity statement for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Attribute must be above photoid property..

```
public class Location
{
    [Column("LocationID")]
    public long LocationID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ID")]
    public long? PhotoID { get; set; }

    public virtual Photo Photo{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: After correcting the placement of the attribute I get an empty migration. I'm wondering if what I'm trying to do is even possible.